# Create general method to fit interface and general parent class

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have the following method:

```
private void setFilledAndAdd(Shape obj, Color col, int x, int y) {
        obj.setFilled(true);    // needs interface Fillable
        obj.setFillColor(col);
        add(obj, x, y);         // needs children of Shape (or Shape itself)
    }
```

If I add one of the lines:

```
setFilledAndAdd(oval, color, x, y);
```

Compile time error apears in line `obj.setFilled(true);` and line`obj.setFillColor(col);`. Because `Shape` is not `Fillable`.  Undefined for the type Shape.
Changing argument type in method `setFilledAndAdd` for `Fillable` (not `Shape`) leads to compile time error in line `add(obj, x, y);`. It needs `Shape` in this case.
All children of `Shape` I use are `Fillable`.
Give me a hint, how to get this method working.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you ever actually create a `Shape` object? Perhaps it would be better to use `Shape` as an abstract class that is Fillable, and all of the "children" of `Shape` actually have the implementation of the `setFilled()` and `setFillColor()` methods?

Comment: "Children" have all these methods. Thanks. The @hexafraction answer is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics to say that you expect an object that has both characteristics

```
private  <T extends Shape & Fillable> void setFilledAndAdd(T obj, Color color, int x, int y){
    obj.setFilled(true);    // needs interface Fillable
    obj.setFillColor(color);
    add(obj, x, y);
}

private void add(Shape s, int x, int y){
    // whatever code you have goes here.
}
```

This compiles just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the `Shape` and `Fillable` source, I would just rewrite so that all shapes are fillable, if that is possible. You could also have a `public abstract class FillableShape extends Shape implements Fillable` instead to keep using the type system.

Otherwise you can use a type-cast, with a runtime check to make sure the shape is fillable:

```
if(obj instanceof Fillable){
    ((Fillable) obj).setFilled(true);    
    ((Fillable) obj).setFillColor(col);
    add(obj, x, y);         
} else {
    // show an error message or something 
    // (or just draw the shape without filling it, if you want)
}
```